# How can I install an operating system on non-boot drive?

Tags: operating-systems, hal

The title might mislead a little, I'll explain in to more detail. I bought a new drive and I wish to reinstall my operating system on it (clean install, no image restore) - while I am booted from the old drive.

My end goal is to install an operating system to my pc, while either:
A. Still using the old operating system
B. Installing it on a different computer and mounting it to my pc.

Is it possible? Any guides out there if it is?

Comment: How else would you do it?  Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Well, lets say I have a drive called F:/ in which I want to install said os. Can I do it while I am booted from drive C:/ (where original os is installed) and not from the install cd?

Comment: Installing an OS on a drive is just writing content to it.  In order to do any form of that, you need to be booted in some OS, and the source content needs to be somewhere accessible (could be on a CD or on a hard drive, including the one you booted on).

Comment: @fixer1234 As far as I know, and please correct me if I am wrong, during installation it reads information about the mobo and hw and adjusts the os accordingly. This process, or a derivation of it, is a reboot to the system. My question is, can I avoid all that?

Comment: In an enterprise environment, you can write a fully-configured version of the OS to the target drive.  For a one-up situation, installation normally includes some configuration for the hardware.  At a minimum, it needs the right drivers.  If you're running an installation routine (as opposed to just writing a generic ISO to the drive), that configuration would be part of what is being written to the drive.  At the point where a reboot would be required, everything needed to complete the installation would have to be already on the drive.  So you could reboot later to finish.